# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Ubuntu's [fifth moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: terdon] [image: Thomas W.]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5667639758159872/0).

Comment: **Congratulations guys!**

Comment: Congrats to both!!

Comment: Congratulations you guys :)

Comment: Already mentioned in chat, congratulations guys!

Comment: This is a perfect choice. We now have two good new mods. Good luck!

Comment: Congratulations guys whoohoo. Welcome to the team.

Comment: Congratulations, both!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: No offence to terdon or Thomas, but great work andrew.46 and Jacob as they came very close.

Comment: "Exhausted" seems to have done pretty well by the end, even despite the name!  I think future candidates ought to watch out for them next time and maybe consider what they're bringing to the election platform. :-p

Comment: And of course, Congrats!  :-)

Comment: How mod elections pass so quickly, GG and good luck!

Comment: Congratulations terdon and Thomas W. This was the first time I got eligible for voting in election and I must say I learnt some very good things through all stages of election.

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators and also to all of those who did not win. It was a pleasure to compete with you in this election. For those who are interested, I evaluated the voting data and uploaded the OpenSTV results to my GitHub website. **[You can view the detailed election results here!](https://bytecommander.github.io/result.html)**

Comment: What strikes me is that only about 8 percent of the eligible voters actually has cast a vote.  Is the involvement of the users really that low? By all means moderators are the people that keep the site running in a certain sense, so this election is important to participate in. Congratulations to the new moderators.

Comment: Haven't been around for a while, real life is kicking in (hardly), but indeed I found the time to partecipate to the elections, and I couldn't be happier with the results. Congrats to both from me as well! I'm positive you won't disappoint us.

Comment: Congs guys.. really happy for yah and hope it all goes well

Comment: Congratulations, It'll be good to see some new mods around now and then! Wait, what? 8%, seriously? Man, that's more shocking than voting turnouts in some UK referendums in the past...

Comment: @ByteCommander Get ready, you are next.

Comment: Congratulations to all!..

Answer (score 55):

Thank you all for your support and votes. I'll try not to let you down!

Comment: Welcome... to the Twilight Zone ;>

Comment: Congrats terdon.

Comment: Thank you for your years of past and future service to the community!

Answer (score 55):

Thank you to everyone who voted!  I thank you all for your support and your votes as well, and will try not to let you down!

Comment: GG congrats and we will hope to see you in action, not too soon?

Comment: Welcome! Now you must undergo the initiation!

Comment: Congrats Thomas W

Comment: Thank you for your years of past and future service to the community!